# Color differences driving me mad?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, color, color-management, filmic-blender

So I've been struggling with color discrepancies between Blender and other softwares, or just Windows.
When I export my render as a .png file and view it within Windows, the colors appear desaturated or oversaturated even though my image is in the sRGB color profile and so is my monitor (LG 27GL850).

I'm struggling to understand which one is showing me the truth, and which one isn't.

When testing via Instagram, the preview image will be oversaturated, but as soon as I get to the filter page, it's desaturated. Pretty confusing.

Has anyone found a fix for this ?
Thank you very much.

[image: Color differences]
[image: Instagram]

Comment: It seems like an issue with Instagram - if viewing the same image file produces different results, outside of Blender.

Comment: The first row of 3 pictures is within Windows, big color difference between the Gmail preview and the Windows viewer for example. That's what I'm struggling to understand.

Comment: Color management in windows is kind of a nightmare, and individual apps may be set to use (or not) your color profile

Comment: I found pre-made filters don't work with instagram but if you modify the sliders yourself (lower right button in your image) it does work. I don't know if this is blender related though...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest disabling color-management all together to see if that solves the issue.

This can be done by going to <kbd>Render Properties > Color Management > Display Device -> None</kbd>

[image]

Comment: +1 from me. This probably does not solve the problem in the question, but it really solves the problem from the perspective from Blender - at least to my understanding, I don't know if maybe Blender saves some color profile or something similar to a PNG file anyway.

Comment: Of course the image produced is ugly, but the point is not to make that an end result but to see how it compares in different apps in this form.